# Is it Fraud action to answer a question from someone sitting right next to me?

Tags: support

I was wondering if **it is considered a Vote Fraud** kind of action here to answer a question that was asked by someone who is actually sitting with you in the same room.

Comment: It is allowed to answer your own questions. Want to guess?

Comment: This question is too vague, and needs to be edited, otherwise it is going to end up closed as not a real question

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: @MichaelTodd What if it was frowned upon? For some that is reason enough not to do it.

Comment: If you and your friend or co-worker are trying to set up a rep-earning network, then all I have to say is I *strongly* recommend against it. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @MichaelTodd I absolutely agree.

Comment: Maybe I'm just cynical, but this looks a bit like testing the waters for some vote fraud to me. I think answering your own question with a sockpuppet is actually allowed, but of course you'd be prohibited from voting on it or accepting it.

Comment: As far as I know "Cousin It" does not use stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i saw that with my own eyes.
Two friends in a cafe' asking on stackoverflow.com and voting up their questions also answering it.
of course i'm not gonna provide names ..
i knew i would get down voted a lot.

Comment: Will, then i will feel no guilt talking some friends in for voting this up for me .

Comment: @AhmedSamir mods are good puppet hunters. Not even Kermit will escape their grasp. Rest assured, they will be caught eventually and all that scheming would go to waste.

Comment: @PHWD HOW is this possible ?

Comment: Sekrit powers of moderators.

Comment: ...why not just talk to each other, and answer each others' questions without Stack Overflow being in the middle? O.o

Comment: @DavidThomas : Are you serious ?!

Comment: how can i take this question back ?!

Comment: No, you can't take it back. *We're onto you now!*

Comment: @AhmedSamir [Y SO SRS?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KI0LQ.jpg)

Comment: OMG, thank you anyway.

Comment: That latest edit changed the question too much as "fraud" was never used in the earlier revisions so none of the answers now address that. I suggest you rollback that edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with answering the question for someone sitting next to you, provided that:

1. Other answers are being considered with the same weight as your own.
2. There does not appear to be any abuse of the system.

Now... That said... Don't even *think* about voting and picking each others posts as best just because of proximity. You're not going to be friends that long anyhow, and *these questions are here **forever***.

That and TylerShads gets angry.

Comment: [TYLERSHADS SMASHHHHHHH!!!!!!](http://devastatingexplosions.com/)

Comment: DEAR GOD! DON'T MAKE HIM ANGRY! YOU WOULDN'T LIKE @TylerShads WHEN HE'S ANGRY!

Answer (score 7):

Technically *It is perfectly fine*.

However, if a trend develops that you and another user are asking and answering each others questions and voting for each other, mod intervention may occur as that would be construed as **gaming the system**.

This would be followed by *at least* moderator contact and *at worst* a suspension from the site.

Comment: Technically, I think the answer you're looking for is *Yes*. :-)

Comment: Aye, whoops!  :P

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

There is nothing wrong with it. It would be no different than [answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking). The only problem would be if you up vote the question, as that may cause a moderator to suspect you of [Vote Fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/what-is-a-vote-fraud), so be careful about that.

Comment: Voting is fine if you feel that the post genuinely deserves it. I referred a friend to Phy.SE, and I've upvoted all her posts--not because I know her, but because they were great.  I upvote anything that's good on P.SE.

Comment: Frankly, you have to be doing some *really* unusual stuff to get accused of voting fraud for this. Thousands of users have a few votes for co-workers on their records - it's the ones who have *nothing but* votes for and answers from others from the same IPs that tend to make the mods skeptical of their intentions. If nothing else, SO was never intended to be an internal helpdesk.

Comment: @Shog9 any chance you're talking about [this (supposedly) poor guy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130011)?