# Why does a second bounty have to be double the amount of the first one?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, expired-bounty

I asked a question which got very little attention due to its specific topic, so I offered a 100 rep bounty for it. After the bounty being set, this one guy was spending *a lot* of time helping me, and the problem turned out to be way harder than I had originally thought. I'd love to give him another +50 or even +100 rep, but apparently I have to double the bounty amount from last time. If I offer too little (100 instead of 150), why am I'm forced to give too much (300)? This ended up with me *not* giving another bounty when he deserved one.

I suggest adding a way to directly reward a bounty to a person *without* having to double the reward's size. To prevent [abusing of the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit) by giving additional attention to the question, this bounty should go "silently" to the other person without any bounty notifications.

Comment: Directly awarding reputation through a bounty would encourage and allow bad players to game the system.

Comment: Might be, but how? Doesn't the system already have this, but it just forces doubling the amount (which is exactly what this question is against)?

Comment: Having a requirement to double the reputation makes transferring to a user reputation difficult, which is the entire point, of said requirement.  A bounty isn't, about the author of the answer, it's about the answer itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is mass bountying considered vote fraud?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134477/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278258/282094

Answer (score 6):

Because of the amount of attention a bounty provides, it was found that users could keep adding +50 bounties repeatedly and would gain more than enough upvotes to make up the amount spent.<sup>1</sup> This is an effort to minimize this gamesmanship without removing the ability to add subsequent bounties.

See: [“Abusing” bounties for unlimited profit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105275/21960)

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, this will only be true on a high-volume site like Stack Overflow.

Comment: I see, that sure does make sense. I feel like it hurts the actual purpose though, would it be possible to add a way to directly grant bounty on an already existing answer? This would end up *not* giving any more attention to the question, and it would be just a bit more than "thank you".

Comment: One of the reasons for a bounty is to "reward already existing answer", but it still marks the question has having a bounty and could prompt others to answer, and is still subject to the doubling requirement. Don't get the idea to go to someone's profile and find a number of their answers to upvote either, since that's serial upvoting and will be rolled back by the system.

Comment: Virtually everything you could possibly want to know can be found at [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/21960)

Comment: This question is tagged as a `feature-request`, "would it be possible to add a way to directly grant bounty on an already existing answer?" was more of a suggestion than it was a question on how the system works.

Comment: If your question is supposed to be a feature request, it doesn't read that way. You probably want to  clarify.

Comment: Alright, hopefully that clarifies a little.